# Select dates based on conditions in R

Tags: r, date, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I am aiming to create a column based on conditions from 2 Date columns. The dataset looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","345","5","345","567","79"),
                 date_of_covid_test = c(2020-04-02, 2000-03-01, 2000-01-01, 2020-11-03, 2020-04-02, 2020-12-05),
                 date_of_hospitalization = c(2020-03-27, 2000-03-25, 2000-03-01, 2020-03-10, NA, NA), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The new column that I want to create is called **"hospitalized_due_to_covid"**. And it is based on being hospitalized **("date_of_hospitalization")** between 1 week before the test **("date_of_covid_test")** & 1 month after the test.

If there is an `NA`, then the outcome would be a `FALSE`.

*The outcome of the example that I posted here would be:*

```
hospitalized_due_to_covid = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

How could I code this?

Thank you very much in advance!!
:)

Comment: Please check your `df`. `date_of_covid_test` and `date_of_hospitalization` are numbers and not dates.

Comment: I am not sure how to change it :( I am going to try your suggestion - million thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(date_of_covid_test, date_of_hospitalization), as.Date), 
         hospitalized_due_to_covid = date_of_hospitalization >= (date_of_covid_test - 7) & 
                                        date_of_hospitalization <= (date_of_covid_test %m+% months(1)), 
         hospitalized_due_to_covid = replace(hospitalized_due_to_covid, is.na(hospitalized_due_to_covid), FALSE))

#  PatientID date_of_covid_test date_of_hospitalization hospitalized_due_to_covid
#1      3454         2020-04-02              2020-03-27                      TRUE
#2       345         2000-03-01              2000-03-25                      TRUE
#3         5         2000-01-01              2000-03-01                     FALSE
#4       345         2020-11-03              2020-03-10                     FALSE
#5       567         2020-04-02                    <NA>                     FALSE
#6        79         2020-12-05                    <NA>                     FALSE
```

where your data is like :

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","345","5","345","567","79"),
                 date_of_covid_test = c("2020-04-02", "2000-03-01", "2000-01-01", "2020-11-03", "2020-04-02", "2020-12-05"),
                 date_of_hospitalization = c("2020-03-27", "2000-03-25", "2000-03-01", "2020-03-10", NA, NA), stringsAsFactors = F)
```